# C# and XNA display more than one text

Tags: c#, if-statement, xna, drawstring

I want to show more than one text with the C# and XNA. The situation is like this. If `A` then display `AAAAA`; If `B` after 'A' then display `BBBB` and `AAAA` at the same time.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
if (Score == A)
{
    spriteBatch.DrawString(
        Font,                          
        "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",  
        scorePos,                     
        Color.White);
}
 if (Score == B)
{
    spriteBatch.DrawString(
        Font,                         
        "BBBBBBBBBBB",  
        scorePos2,                     
        Color.White);
}
```

However, if I display `BBB`, `AAA` disappears; what I should I use instead of my `If` statement?

Comment: `If A then display AAAAA, if B then display BBBB` I don't see that logic in your code, only a comparison to the Score.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? I don't see why you can't just remove the if block here. You know what conditions are, right? And your A B conditions don't really translate well with your code example that follows.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I understand there is problem in the code. Other than using "If else", what should I use please?

Comment: Hello all, thank you all for your kindly reply. My situation is like this: If score == A , then show "AAAAA", or score== B, then show "BBBB" but I still want to show "AAAAA" on the screen when I show "BBBB", what should I do please?

Comment: Why do you have  `If score == A , then show "AAAAA"` if `AAAAA` has to be displayed whatever the state is? Just display `AAAAA` outside of the `if` clause. Your requirement is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, it is my fault to confuse everybody. Let me explain it again. I have two situation. Either A or B, and not matter which one appear first, I want to display the corresponding text, what is more, If A appear first, and B appear later, when I show "BBB" and I still want to show "AAA" on the screen.

Comment: You could say `"BBBBBBBBBBB" + "AAAAAAAAAAAAA"` - that makes one string out of two.

Comment: Thanks, but if I have more than 10 situations, this method might be a little bit difficult.

Comment: You've just introduced a time factor in the equation. So the same method is called multiple times, and if `AAA` has already been displayed in a previous call, it needs to stay where it was. Is that it? It's still not clear how `A` should be updated, whether `B` should be cleared between two calls, and so on. Posting the whole method (with its signature) and explaining the role of each variable would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its still not *entirely* clear what behavior you want, but it seems you don't understand what `else` does.

An `else` (or `else if`) statement will **only** execute if the `if`/`else if` statements above it do not.

With your code, this means that you will only ever execute the "A" block **or** the "B" block, never both.

If you just want "A" to print As and "B" to print Bs (independent of each other), just don't use `else`:

```
if (A)
{
}
if (B)
{
}
```

If you only want to print Bs if you have As, then nest them:

```
if (A)
{
   if (B)
   {
   }
}
```

Honestly, I doubt you want any `else` structures in your current code. You do have the additional problem of checking equality on the `Score` variable. `Score` can never equal "A" and "B" at the same time, so you could never get into both conditions as it stands anyways. You'll need to find a different condition to check.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have typo before and I fixed it. Yes, you are right, I can't have both A and B if I use "else" statement.

Comment: @user3684119 You still have the problem of mutually exclusive conditions. You need to find a different way to determine which to draw, because they will never be true together.

Comment: I have thought about using nested if as your second example. But either A or B will appear first, so the outer if might be difficult to decide. And I have A,B,C,D, etc, the nested if would be a little bit difficult?  Thanks again.

Comment: @user3684119 It all depends on what the rules are. Only nest if performing the inner code depends on the outer condition being true.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the reply. I find my question stupid when I figure out the answer. Just define two variable can solve the problem, the modified coed is like

```
        if (Score == 1)
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(
                Font,                          // SpriteFont
                "AAAAAAA",  // Text
                scorePos,                      // Position
                Color.White);
         }//end of H2

        ////If O2 matched, score=2
        if (Score2 == 1)
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(
                Font,                          // SpriteFont
                "BBBBBBBB",  // Text
                scorePos3,                      // Position
                Color.White);
        }//end of O2
```